# Blocking the default listbox scrolling in Python running on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, listbox

My environment is Python 2.7, running on Windows 7.

When I create a Tkinter window with two scrolling listboxes, the default behavior is that Windows will direct the mousewheel action to whichever of them has the focus.  Each increment of the mousewheel moves 4 lines up/down. When the focus leaves the listbox, it stops responding to the mousewheel.

Ultimately I'm looking to completely replace this behavior with my own bindings.  I've written the code for that and it yields the new custom response I want, but the problem is that the default behavior still occurs as well, based on the listbox that has the focus.  I can't seem to block it no matter what I try.

Here's a simplified code sample to illustrate.  I'm expecting that my binding to the `<FocusIn>` event (with its `return 'break'` line) would prevent the default mousewheel response, but still occurs.  I tried intercepting the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event as well, but that doesn't block it either.  It doesn't even help when I do a `bind_all` on the `<Mousewheel>` event; somehow the default response still gets triggered.

```
import Tkinter as tk

#Root window
root = tk.Tk()

#Widgets
ctrl1 = tk.StringVar()
vsb1 = tk.Scrollbar(root,
                    orient=tk.VERTICAL)
lst1 = tk.Listbox(root,
                  width=20,height=10,
                  listvariable=ctrl1,
                  activestyle='dotbox',
                  yscrollcommand=vsb1.set)
vsb1.config(command=lst1.yview)

ctrl2 = tk.StringVar()
vsb2 = tk.Scrollbar(root,
                    orient=tk.VERTICAL)
lst2 = tk.Listbox(root,
                  width=20,height=10,
                  listvariable=ctrl2,
                  activestyle='dotbox',
                  yscrollcommand=vsb2.set)
vsb2.config(command=lst2.yview)

#Geometry
lst1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.NSEW,padx=(5,0),pady=5)
vsb1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.NS,padx=(0,5),pady=5)
lst2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=tk.NSEW,padx=(15,0),pady=5)
vsb2.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=tk.NS,padx=(0,5),pady=5)

#Bindings
def focusIn1(*args):
    print 'Focus in 1'
    return 'break'

def focusIn2(*args):
    print 'Focus in 2'
    return 'break'

lst1.bind('<FocusIn>',focusIn1)
lst2.bind('<FocusIn>',focusIn2)

#Dummy listbox content
ctrl1.set('Entry-index-00 Entry-index-01 Entry-index-02 Entry-index-03 '+ \
         'Entry-index-04 Entry-index-05 Entry-index-06 Entry-index-07 '+ \
         'Entry-index-08 Entry-index-09 Entry-index-10 Entry-index-11 '+ \
         'Entry-index-12 Entry-index-13 Entry-index-14 Entry-index-15 '+ \
         'Entry-index-16 Entry-index-17 Entry-index-18 Entry-index-19 <end-of-queue>')

ctrl2.set('Entry-index-00 Entry-index-01 Entry-index-02 Entry-index-03 '+ \
         'Entry-index-04 Entry-index-05 Entry-index-06 Entry-index-07 '+ \
         'Entry-index-08 Entry-index-09 Entry-index-10 Entry-index-11 '+ \
         'Entry-index-12 Entry-index-13 Entry-index-14 Entry-index-15 '+ \
         'Entry-index-16 Entry-index-17 Entry-index-18 Entry-index-19 <end-of-queue>')

#Begin app
tk.mainloop()
```

Is there some other event I need to intercept instead?  Or is there maybe some different approach I need to use to block the default mousewheel response?

*(Just in case it matters... the custom behavior I'm aiming for is to have single-line scrolling of one listbox or the other independently, based solely on whether the mouse pointer is within that listbox.  Because of the described issue, if (say) listbox #1 has the focus and the pointer is over listbox #2, they gang-scroll in response to the mousewheel, with #2 scrolling one line at a time while #1 scrolls 4 lines at a time.  If I switch and point to #1, it scrolls by itself but it still scrolls 4 lines at a time instead of 1.)*

EDIT:  Binding that references the `<MouseWheel>` event, but still fails to block the default scrolling behavior.  I put this in place of the `<FocusIn>` events.

```
#Bindings
def scrollBlock(*args):
    print "Blocking scrolling (except it won't)"
    return "break"

root.bind_all('<MouseWheel>',scrollBlock)
```

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of the mouse wheel, you're going to have to create your own bindings for the mouse wheel. Binding in `<Enter>`, `<Leave>`, or `<<ListboxSelect>>` have nothing to do with the mouse wheel.

Comment: See last paragraph before the code sample -- I tried a `<Mousewheel>` binding but to no avail.

Comment: Sure, you said you tried it, but your code doesn't show that. If you tried it and it didn't work, you did something wrong. What you want is doable, but without seeing what you tried, it's hard for us to fix your code.

Comment: Substitute snippet added via edit.

Comment: @BryanOakley, does the edit cover what you needed?  (The more I think about this, the more I suspect this is a quirk of the Windows Tkinter implementation, one that can't be bypassed or overridden.)